# How can I delimit the width of a trendline?

Tags: graphics, qlikview, trendline

I have these variables:

X = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)

Y = (1, 5, 4, 9, 7, 8, 12, 20, 9, 7, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1)

and I want to do a graphic with two visible partitions (X from 1 to 8 and X from 9 to 16). So, I set one dimension X and two expressions IF (X <= 8,Y) and IF (X > 8,Y). It works well and I got this:

[Basic graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSL6i.png)

Now I want to include the linear trend line. But, after click in the proper option in the expressions tab, I got this:

[Graphic with trend lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTIwy.png)

which is not a good thing to see. I wished something like this:

[Wished graphic with trend lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/857sD.png)

Anyone knows how can I get a graphic like this last picture?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want manually to calculate the linear Regression you have to use these functions `LINEST_B` and `LINEST_M` like this:

```
linest_M(total aggr(Y,X),X)*X+ linest_b(total aggr(Y,X),X)
```

but with some modifications because you split your expressions.

Here is an example with your data set:
[image]

[Here](https://filebin.net/n9jgbwp8y5soyi58) is the whole file

[from Qliks' help](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/November2017/Subsystems/Client/Content/ChartFunctions/NestedAggregations/linear-regression-table-charts.htm)

Comment: @Marcelo please mark this answer as correct if it was the right answer to your question